# VLOOKUP function not working

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, vlookup

I'm struggling with understanding why this doesn't work...The code doesn't crash but in the Watch window each value of the `VLookUpsStorer` are "Error 2042".
Can someone help me spot the error ?

```
Dim I As Long
Dim VLookUpsStorer As Variant
ReDim VLookUpsStorer(1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1 To 3) As Variant
Dim TotalRows As Integer
TotalRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet1")
   For I = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & I) <> "" Then
           VLookUpsStorer(I - 1, 1) = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & I), .Range("C2:D" & TotalRows), 2, False)
           VLookUpsStorer(I - 1, 2) = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & I), .Range("C2:E" & TotalRows), 3, False
           VLookUpsStorer(I - 1, 3) = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & I), .Range("C2:F" & TotalRows), 4, False)
      Else
                Exit For
      End If
   Next I
End With
Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 9)) = VLookUpsStorer
```

EDIT : Tests done [image]

EDIT 2 : Sample of what the 2 sheets look like (before I put them both with the same General format (but no differences))

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUpNs.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHsIc.png)

Comment: That means that your lookup values are not being found. Hard to say why from what you've posted.

Comment: See some tests (EDIT) I have done. It might be a format issue, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Rory : The lookup path is correct for sure

Comment: I didn't say anything about the path. It means the value you are looking up is not found in column C on Sheet1. If you are looking up numeric data, both must be either true numbers, or text representations of numbers.

Comment: I ensured manually that all those columns have the same format ( I tried firstly with Text and secondly with General), but no difference

Comment: Changing the format won't affect the data that's already in there. You'd need to re-enter it.

Comment: Yes, just did it. I cut the data, reformatted properly the columns in question and pastes the values of the data inside. But still the same error occurs

Comment: When I record a Vlookup macro, it doesn't recognize the lookup value as a cell. Let's take a row, the Vlookup expected is `=VLOOKUP(A3,'Sheet1'!C:D,2,0)` but instead the recorded macro is (for all rows) `=VLOOKUP([@VIN],'Sheet1'!C[-4]:C[-3],2)`

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain and roll your own lookup function using for loops. With VLookup theres so much that can go wrong.

Comment: Cut/copy and paste would replace the original format too. You need to copy and paste values only. Are the values numeric? (your recorded macro formula is using structured table references)

Comment: @Absinthe : Yes this is what I've done but I am just frustrated about this Vllokup issue...

Comment: @Rory : I did paste the values only yes but it didn't work neither. The values are not purely numeric no, so that's why I set the format everywhere to General but still same issue occured. I ended up avoiding the issue by using arrays rather than this Vlookup function

Comment: I can't say why without seeing the actual data. For whatever reason, the values in Sheet2 column A don't match the data in Sheet1 column C.

Comment: @Rory : I edit my question with a screenshot of what value I am looking for. I hided all the other unrelated data

Comment: I actually tried to use the same structure for another VLookup with totally different data and I get the same exact error. Seems like the error is not related to the values but to my code somewhere

Comment: A picture doesn't really help, especially a pic of two values that clearly *don't* match. Can you post a link to a suitably censored file?

Comment: Unrelated - I provided a (late) answer to your [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163666/vlookup-simulation-copying-data-from-one-sheet-to-another/169517#169517) question